# angular-oauth2-oidc: Does redirect_uri have to be /index.html?

Tags: angular, pkce, angular-oauth2-oidc

In the `PKCE` example of the `angular-oauth2-oidc` library

https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/code-flow-+-pcke.html

The `redirect_uri` is

```
window.location.origin + '/index.html'
```

Is this important from a security point of view?

When I add the `/index.html`, I get a `Page Not Found` error in my app after redirecting from the auth server.

But when I do it like this:

```
window.location.origin
```

it works.

Does this have to work with `index.html` and I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you ever visit `http://yourdomain:yourport/index.html`? What happens when you visit this URL? The chances are that it does not exist. In an Angular app all routes serve index.html - that is what a Single Page Application is by definition. Maybe you have a home route - e.g. /home

You should redirect to your home route not index.html.

Basically you want:

```
window.location.origin + '/home'
```

Or even better:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

this.router.navigateByUrl('/home')
```

Redirecting to:

```
window.location.origin
```

Is essentially just the domain and port of the current page - e.g. `http://yourdomain:yourport` - so redirecting is essentially just sending you to your default Angular route. Your default Angular route should be defined in your app routing .ts file. Sometimes there's a "catch all" route in there which I would expect would be picked up if no specific route is defined in the URL.

Basically just visit ... `http://yourdomain:yourport` ... in the browser. Whatever page you hit is where redirecting to `window.location.origin` should take you to.

In the docs you link to they say:

> URL of the SPA to redirect the user to after login
> redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/index.html'

This is just an example and should not be hardcoded like this!

Comment: Yes, opening app:port/index.html directly in the browser does not work. The default route is /, which is also handled in the routing-module by path:''. Thats where I want to be redirected to.

The reason I wondered is because before switching to PKCE I used the implicit flow and there it worked for some reason.